# Trying to give this image a round frame, thus eliminating the sharp edges of the image

Tags: html, css, image, transform, scale

[a group of young people working on their PCs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45WYW.png)

Been trying to add a round frame around this image and eliminate the sharp corners and possibly design the frame

Comment: `border-radius`

Comment: If you want to achieve this using CSS then something as simple as 
`border-radius:50%` and `border: 1px solid black` can work

Comment: Tried that, it did not work. Much more than the border radius. I want to enclose the image in a round frame.

Comment: The border-radius gave the image an oval shape as opposed the circular shape I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is rectangular, this is why when you apply border-radius: 50% you see an oval shape.

Try resizing picture to square and then applying border-radius:

```
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
```

Comment: Yes the picture is rectangular. Thanks so much, was able to solve it.